# HighDPI retina windows in pyglet

Tags: python, opengl, retina-display, pyglet, highdpi

Is there a way to create a retina window in pyglet?

The default `pyglet.window.Window()` creates a window that is blurry on my retina screen. Is there a setting in pyglet or do I have to dive into the Open GL plumbing to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that pyglet 1.3 is not aware of Retina displays. Despite of what [pyglet window doc](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/pyglet-1.3-maintenance/modules/window.html#pyglet.window.Window) says, the `window.get_size()` method returns **points** instead of **pixels**. That's an issue coming from the way Apple has designed High Resolution stuff.

Apple info:

- [High Resolution for OS
  X](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/HighResolutionOSX/Introduction/Introduction.html)
- [Enable OpenGL for High-Resolution Drawing](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/HighResolutionOSX/CapturingScreenContents/CapturingScreenContents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012302-CH10-SW33)

Likely you can't use the `setWantsBestResolutionOpenGLSurface` parameter.

So your best bet is **doubling the sizes to be used at glViewport**. And following this path, also double the sizes (2x*2y = 4*x*y) of FBO buffers, textures, and positions.